# Robolectric Handler post() not working as expected

Tags: android, robolectric

I have the following code

```kotlin
class ClassToTest {
    fun doSomething() {
        Handler().post {
            println("some work by handler")
        }
    }
}
```

and the following test code

```kotlin
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(sdk = [Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1])
class TestClass {
    @Test
    fun `test do something`() {
        val underTest = ClassToTest()
        underTest.doSomething()
    }
}
```

My print statement or whatever inside Handler#post is apparently not getting called

Why?

Robolectric version 4.7.3
Java version 11
compileSdk 30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution thanks to this post, adding `shadowOf(getMainLooper()).idle()` triggers the stuffs in inside `post {}`

```kotlin
@Test
    fun `test do something`() {
        val underTest = ClassToTest()
        underTest.doSomething()
        shadowOf(getMainLooper()).idle()
    }
```